# Balance not showing

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I wanted to have 2 xmr address's so I went to open my wallet w pw and pushed cancel and created new wallet. I read that there was a switch wallet button under settings. I don't see that so I said ok np I'll restore my wallet from seed. I entered the 25 words put the height to a Cpl blocks short of current height entered my pw twice and started the gui. Showed synchronizing for about half he now it shows connected I checked block height under settings I'm at current height. I don't see the funds nor any transactions from that wallet.

Pls help

Comment: I'd advise to redo the process and use a proper restore height (you can use that ^ SE Q&A for guidance). If you set a restore height close to the current height the wallet will not be able to see transactions that happened before that height (which you likely have).

Comment: There was funds in it at the height I used. 0 transactions show up which is not true of the address. I double checked it to make sure. I have more funds set to go to this address I'm concerned. I'm about to restore from 0 which I've done before with 0 balance.

Comment: What specific height did you use? Also, using restore height 0 is unnecessary (and hammers the remote node if you use one).

Comment: About 100 blocks before current I've had funds in that wallet for a cpl weeks and have used it for almost a year now. I have about 1.3 million blocks left I'll just wait. I've also restored from 0 too. No tx shown no balance. I have more funds set to goto that wallet im getting concerned.

Comment: Then using a restore height of 0 is absolutely unnecessary and unnecessarily hammers the remote (if you're using one)... I'd strongly advise to redo the process with a sane restore height (e.g. `1400000`). Also, are you sure you have the right wallet open? Check if the address on the receive page matches the address you withdrew to.

Comment: I tried it twice from 0 last night both times got stuck synchronizing around block 70k dofferent blocks but both around 70k. I've reatarted again. I'm gonna look into stuck synchronizing here then decide what to do. Yes I checked wallet address to make sure I got the right one.

Comment: Actually that's not true. What happens is I start the Gui again and it asks me for my pw I enter it and it starts about 200k blocks behind. I'm gonna try again from block 1.4 million like u suggested

Comment: Any luck in getting the balance to show properly?

Comment: yes eventually after starting from block 1500000

thanks alot

Comment: All right, good to hear!